# Are questions about equipment instructions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

I have bought an amateur telescope recently.

Can I ask other members detailed questions like "How can I work with my telescope?" or "How do I set my telescope on a specific celestial object to observe?" or "How do I calibrate my telescope?"?

Comment: As the current answer states, a big Yes! You can do a quick check first to see if there's an identical question, but don't worry if there is some overlap only, every telescope and every user is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! That was actually the main hope for the site when it was launched--that it would be a home for this kind of information. Naturally, there end up being a lot of science questions simply because not everyone has access to a telescope, but equipment setup is still perfectly welcome.

Comment: ...and because astronomers like to talk about astronomy without all those rocket-based questions in Space SE. :-) I didn't realize that that was the site's original hope. It still is a great place to ask such questions but I'm also glad there's a place to discuss all aspects of astronomy!

Comment: @uhoh I should clarify: many of the users who signed onto the proposal on Area 51 were interested in the science aspect, but the CM team's hope was that the site would be a good place for amateur astronomers to learn how to setup and use their equipment.